# Does core data create a SQLite database file automatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

does core data create a sqlite database automatically? if yes, why it's not visible?

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]   
URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does, the file is created in the app's documents directory. During development with the simulator you can find it in the simulator folder (now moved to DerivedData in your Xcode folder in Xcode 4.3) if you want to delete it or use your development database to see your app once it installed on a device.